# I want to single deploy WAR file for all environment DEV/UAT/PROD but i ahve dependency of properties file let me know how i will do?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment

*Currently in my comp they are deploying the WAR file in different-2 environment by creating different-different WAR file.*
**Exp: for DEV they will create and deploy,
for UAT they will create and Deploye
due to some dependency of properties file.**

So  i want solution that how i will configure in server side or in WAR file  to deploy single WAR file which is created by Developer only
and its a best practice also.

I heard from others that we can do it by configuring Environment properties related with environment in server side.

please give the perfect solution which should work properly...

Hopine for +ve answer.
Thanks !

Comment: This question covers the complete Enterprise application setup. It is very difficult to explain solution completely.

Comment: in that case do you have any tutorial which is cover these things ,i will g through that.
or any documents if you have can you pls share ??

Comment: Seems like a legit question to me... I wonder why it has downvotes

Answer (score 2):

You can keep different properties files as per the environments like DEV,UAT.
Now in your different environments you can keep an environment variable say env as DEV and UAT.

In Tomcat it can be simply set by giving it in vm options -Denv=DEV or -Denv=UAT.

Now you can create the same war file which will have all the configuration files for all the environments and based on your environment variable it will pick up and configuration file.

Hope is answer your query.

Example :  Below is the war plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <warName>${app.jvm}</warName>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/config</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here we copy *-dev.properties *-uat.properties

Now for example if you are using tomcat server in local

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>8086</port>
        <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
        <systemProperties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Like this you can set the environment variable in tomcat. At the startup of application based on System.getProperty("env") you can pick the config file.

Comment: can you please elaborate it with more explanation ?
like where to set env variable and how will our war will read it and all ?

Comment: or anybody can help me to solve this issue,
Finally we have decided the we will keep properties file in server location not in WAR file.
but i need help 
1. where to keep in Server
2. how we will read the properties file from server location at the time of deploying the WAR
3.  pls prived some piece of code for this 

Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with example, Please try this in local. for development environment or UAT environment in the JVM startup these system property can be set.

Comment: but here properties file will be inside war file right ?
but i want to keep in server location not in WAR file 
like in DEV server for Dev env and for UAT for UAT env etc

Comment: In that case also you can set the environment variable JAVAOPTS -Denv=dev in JVM and use any script which will run during server startup and copy your respective configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 properties file in your project

1. Application.local.properties
2. Application.dev.properties

When you execute the build set your vm parameters

When you want use local then set as  -Denv=local

For dev:   -Denv=dev

This will read related for.